# Fill missing dates while using Grouper with multiple keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a timeseries dataset containing the consumption of different materials over 3 years. I'm trying to aggregate this dataset at material level, containing its consumption month over month. While I'm able to do this using Grouper with multiple keys, the months with 0 consumption are missing in the final output. Can someone help me how to include these months?

I tried using the pandas Grouper with multiple keys.

```
grouper = pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='MS')
consumption_grouped = consumption.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Material'),grouper])['QtyConsumed'].sum().reset_index()
```

Expected

```
Date          QtyConsumed
2017-08-01   -2.0
2017-09-01   -8.0
2017-10-01   -6.0
2017-11-01   -2.0
2017-12-01    0.0
2018-01-01   -3.0
```

Actual

```
Date          QtyConsumed
2017-08-01   -2.0
2017-09-01   -8.0
2017-10-01   -6.0
2017-11-01   -2.0
2018-01-01   -3.0
```

As you can see above, in the Actual result, entry for 2017-12-01 is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Solution if `MultiIndex` by first 2 columns in input `DataFrame` create `DatetimeIndex` first by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) only `Material` level, then use `groupby` with [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) and `sum`:

```
print (df)
                     QtyConsumed
Material Date                   
mat1     2017-08-01         -2.0
         2017-09-01         -8.0
         2017-10-01         -6.0
         2017-11-01         -2.0
         2018-01-01         -3.0
mat2     2017-08-01         -2.0
         2017-09-01         -8.0
         2017-10-01         -6.0
         2017-11-01         -2.0
         2018-01-01         -3.0
mat3     2017-08-01         -2.0
         2017-09-01         -8.0
         2017-10-01         -6.0
         2017-11-01         -2.0
         2018-01-01         -3.0
```

---

```
df = (df.reset_index(level=['Material'])
        .groupby('Material')
        .resample('MS')['QtyConsumed']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   Material       Date  QtyConsumed
0      mat1 2017-08-01         -2.0
1      mat1 2017-09-01         -8.0
2      mat1 2017-10-01         -6.0
3      mat1 2017-11-01         -2.0
4      mat1 2017-12-01          0.0
5      mat1 2018-01-01         -3.0
6      mat2 2017-08-01         -2.0
7      mat2 2017-09-01         -8.0
8      mat2 2017-10-01         -6.0
9      mat2 2017-11-01         -2.0
10     mat2 2017-12-01          0.0
11     mat2 2018-01-01         -3.0
12     mat3 2017-08-01         -2.0
13     mat3 2017-09-01         -8.0
14     mat3 2017-10-01         -6.0
15     mat3 2017-11-01         -2.0
16     mat3 2017-12-01          0.0
17     mat3 2018-01-01         -3.0
```

If only `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print (df)
           Material  QtyConsumed
Date                            
2017-08-01     mat1         -2.0
2017-09-01     mat1         -8.0
2017-10-01     mat1         -6.0
2017-11-01     mat1         -2.0
2018-01-01     mat1         -3.0
2017-08-01     mat2         -2.0
2017-09-01     mat2         -8.0
2017-10-01     mat2         -6.0
2017-11-01     mat2         -2.0
2018-01-01     mat2         -3.0
2017-08-01     mat3         -2.0
2017-09-01     mat3         -8.0
2017-10-01     mat3         -6.0
2017-11-01     mat3         -2.0
2018-01-01     mat3         -3.0
```

---

```
df = (df.groupby('Material')
        .resample('MS')['QtyConsumed']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   Material       Date  QtyConsumed
0      mat1 2017-08-01         -2.0
1      mat1 2017-09-01         -8.0
2      mat1 2017-10-01         -6.0
3      mat1 2017-11-01         -2.0
4      mat1 2017-12-01          0.0
5      mat1 2018-01-01         -3.0
6      mat2 2017-08-01         -2.0
7      mat2 2017-09-01         -8.0
8      mat2 2017-10-01         -6.0
9      mat2 2017-11-01         -2.0
10     mat2 2017-12-01          0.0
11     mat2 2018-01-01         -3.0
12     mat3 2017-08-01         -2.0
13     mat3 2017-09-01         -8.0
14     mat3 2017-10-01         -6.0
15     mat3 2017-11-01         -2.0
16     mat3 2017-12-01          0.0
17     mat3 2018-01-01         -3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to resample, not group

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date').resample('MS').last().fillna(0).reset_index()
```

**Input**

```
          Date  QtyConsumed
0   2017-08-01  -2.0
1   2017-09-01  -8.0
2   2017-10-01  -6.0
3   2017-11-01  -2.0
4   2018-01-01  -3.0
```

**Output**

```
         Date   QtyConsumed
0   2017-08-01  -2.0
1   2017-09-01  -8.0
2   2017-10-01  -6.0
3   2017-11-01  -2.0
4   2017-12-01  0.0
5   2018-01-01  -3.0
```